# CSS3 Browser compatibility

Tags: css

The CSS3 transition effect on this [page](http://www.siteripe.com) works perfectly well on every other browser except IE. It also adds a border to the top and to the left of the thumbnails. I have tried making the borders of all the elements 0 but it still didn't help. The css is as shown below.

```
.slide-up-boxes .showbox a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    height: 157px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 315px;
    float: left;
    border:none;
    padding: 0px;
    background: transparent;
        }

        .slide-up-boxes .showbox img { 
            color: #333; 
            text-align: center;
            margin-right: 15px;
            width: 315px;
            float: left;
            height: 157px; 
            font: italic 18px/65px Georgia, Serif;    /* Vertically center text by making line height equal to height */
            zoom: 1;
            filter: alpha(opacity=45);
            opacity: 0.5;
             -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear; 
             -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear; 
             -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        }

    .showbox a:hover img { 
            margin-top: -155px; 
            opacity: 0; 
            height: 157px; 
            width: 315px;

        }

        .showbox object {
    color: white;
    background: #393838;
    font: 12px/15px Georgia, Serif;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transform: rotate(6deg);
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -o-transform: rotate(6deg);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    width: 314px;
    float: left;
    height: 154px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
        }
        .slide-up-boxes .showbox a:hover object { 
            opacity: 1; 
            width: 314px;
            border: none;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0); 
            -moz-transform: rotate(0); 
            -o-transform: rotate(0); 
            zoom: 1;
        }
    .slide-up-boxes .showbox#show1 object { 
    background: url(images/huethumb.jpg) ; 
    padding-top: 110px; zoom: 1;
    border: none;

    }
    .slide-up-boxes .showbox#show2 object { 
    background: url(images/pizzathumb.jpg) ; 
    padding-top: 110px; zoom: 1;
    border: none;

    }
    .slide-up-boxes .showbox#show3 object { 
    background: url(images/rickolthumb.jpg) ; 
    padding-top: 110px;
    border: none;

    }
    .slide-up-boxes .showbox#show4 object { 
    background:url(images/bernie-thumber.jpg) ; 
    padding-top: 110px; zoom: 1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;

    }
    .slide-up-boxes .showbox#show5 object { 
    background: url(images/nollythumb.png) ; 
    padding-top: 110px; zoom: 1;
    border: none;

    }
    .slide-up-boxes .showbox#show6 object { 
    background:url(images/photothumg.jpg) ; 
    padding-top: 110px; zoom: 1;
    border: none;

    }
    .slide-up-boxes .showbox#show7 object { 
    background:url(images/tradersthumb.png) ; 
    padding-top: 110px; zoom: 1;
    border: none;

    }
    .slide-up-boxes .showbox#show8 object { 
    background:url(images/wpbathumb.jpg);
    padding-top: 110px; zoom: 1;
    border: none;

    }
    .slide-up-boxes .showbox#show9 object  { 
    background:url(images/peterthumb.png);
    padding-top: 110px;
    zoom: 1;
    border: none;
    }
```

Comment: How do I make the borders go away when viewed on IE? how do I make the Animation effect work on IE just like other browsers?

Comment: Is it supposed to work in IE? Which version are we talking about here?  When comments indicate inadequate information and ask for clarification, you should edit your question accordingly instead of posting another comment.

Comment: IE 8 and 9. It works but not properly.

Comment: CSS3 is not fully implemented in IE8, AFAIK.  And your CSS3 transitions are specific to only Mozilla, Opera, and Webkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you do with -webkit or -moz will not work with IE, they're browser engine specific css styles.  ms-transform should work in IE9, but there is no transition style.  See this MSDN article on [CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I think helps answer my question. Thank you so much.